# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{-1/2}(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\dots+\frac{1}{a_n})$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> **Question: The sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ is defined by $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=n/a_n$, for all integers $n\geq1$. Evaluate$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{-1/2}(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\dots+\frac{1}{a_n})$$**

My Attempt: I was trying to make the use of AM-GM-HM inequality here, we have $a_{n+1}=n/a_n$, using it for $n\geq1$ we have
$$a_2=1/a_1\\
a_3=2/a_2\\
a_4=3/a_3\\
\dots\\
a_n=(n-1)/a_{n-1}\\
a_{n+1}=n/a_n\\$$
Now multiplying them we get $$a_2 .a_3\dots a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{a_1}.\frac{2}{a_2}\dots\frac{n}{a_n}$$ and $a_1=1$ plugging in or out will not create  must difference. Now from above we have
$$(a_1.a_2\dots a_n)^2=\frac{n!}{a_{n+1}}\\
(a_1.a_2\dots a_n)^{1/n}=(\frac{n!}{a_{n+1}})^{2/n}$$
Using the inequality that I have mentioned here we will have $$(a_!.a_2\dots a_n)^{1/n}\geq\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}\dots+\frac{1}{a_3}}$$
By making some manipulations since there was a term $a_{n+1}, n!$, tried using Stirling's approximation it didn't helped much. Note that no comments on $a_n>0$ are made but I am assuming here $a_n>0$.

Thanks.

Comment: On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1337965p7250173